# Constructing a function $h \in C_0^∞$ such that $h=1$ in $G_1$ and $h=0$ outside $G$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $G$ and $G_1$ be bounded open subsets of $R^n$ such that $\bar{G_1} \subset G$. Construct a function $h \in C_0^∞$ such that $h=1$ in $G_1$ and $h=0$ outside $G$.

We can choose an open set $G_2$ such that $\bar{G_1} \subset G_2, \bar{G}_2 \subset G.$ Now we define $h$. I want to define $h$ in some way that includes a function $C=1 \in C^∞$ (probably with a support that is very small?). How can you approach to solve this problem?

EDIT: sorry the function $h$ should also take into account my defined set $G_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $R>0$ such that $G\subset [-R,R]^n$. Then $\overline {G_1}$ and $[-R,R]^n\setminus G$ are disjoint compact sets, hence have some positive distance $d$.
Note that the maps $x\mapsto \operatorname{dist}(x,\overline {G_1})$ and $x\mapsto \operatorname{dist}(x,G^\complement)$ are continuous, non-negative, and their sum is always $\ge d$, in particular always positive.
Our first attempt is
$$\tag1 f(x)=\frac{\operatorname{dist}(x,G^\complement)}{\operatorname{dist}(x,G^\complement)+\operatorname{dist}(x,\overline {G_1})}.$$
This is  $=1$ in $G_1$ and $=0$ outside $G$, as desired, but it is only continuous. We can turn this into a smooth function by mollifying - but that would make intermediate values "bleed" into $G_1$ and out of $G$! 
So instead of $(1)$, we define $f$ as 
$$\tag1 f(x)=\frac{g(\operatorname{dist}(x,G^\complement))}{g(\operatorname{dist}(x,G^\complement))+g(\operatorname{dist}(x,\overline {G_1}))}$$
where
$$ g(t)=\max\left\{t-\tfrac d3,0\right\}=\begin{cases}0&t\le\frac d3,\\t-\frac d3&t\ge \frac d3.\end{cases}$$
Note that this new $f$ is still continuous (because $g$ s continuous and the numerator is still always positive, in fact always $\ge \frac d3$), is $=0$ and $=1$ in the desired regions, but also at all points at distance at most $\frac d3$ from these regions.
Now let $\phi$ be a smooth function with support in the ball of radius $\frac d3$ and such that $\int\phi(x)\,\mathrm dx=1$. Then let 
$$h(x)=\int f(x-y)\phi(y)\,\mathrm dy.$$
This is smooth because $\phi$ is smooth (even if $f$ is only continuous) and by the small support of $\phi$, we have $h(x)=0$ for $x\in G_1$ as well as $h(x)=0$ for $x\notin G$, as desired.

Comment: I just realized that I think you have a typo in your last sentence? Do you mean $h(x)=1$ for $x \in G_1$?